# формат для чтения файла

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net

Как сделать что бы на сайте `aspx`отобразился текст из файла если сделать обычный .txt файл то текст  отображается `Label1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Portal\Help.txt");`но текст без форматирования просто вряд. Подскажите как можно реализовать что бы текст отображался отформатированный, т.е если текст жирный то и на сайте он должен быть жырным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного быдлокод, но смысл ясен

```
Label1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Portal\Help.txt").Replace("<", " &lt;").Replace(">", " &gt;").Replace("\n", "<br/>");
```